# Setting up dual monitors with GPU and motherboard

Tags: multiple-monitors, cpu, motherboard, bios, gpu

I have two monitors but only one VGA to DVI converter, which I'm using to connect my primary monitor to my GPU. How can I connect my secondary monitor to the motherboard and get it to work?

Note: I know it's not recommended. This is just temporary.

The Motherboard is M4A88T-M/USB3

Edit: Both monitors are VGA. My Motherboard has one VGA and one DVI. My GPU has two DVI (one is in use) and one HDMI.

Comment: You have not told us what connectors your monitors have, or what connectors your graphics card and mainboard have. I'd also guess that knowing those two pieces of information you'd know exactly what connectors are required to get them connected. That said, not every system supports simultaneous video output from both discrete graphics and onboard GPU at the same time.

Comment: Both monitors are VGA. My Motherboard has one VGA and one DVI. My GPU has two DVI (one is in use) and one HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

Since your DVI is in use, use a HDMI to VGA adapter and connect the other monitor.